# Import txt file with space delimiter format

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import a txt file to look from this:

0.022666917564292177

-0.0010678057608304314

0.02583850573101998

-0.004696069157210658

to something like this:

[0.022666917564292177 -0.0010678057608304314 0.02583850573101998 -0.004696069157210658]

I don't know if this format has a name but I need it like this.

Comment: You want a list of all values? Your desired output is a list of int. Right?

Comment: Yes that's right